# When trying to link Nexus Mod Manager to Skyrim, it claims I don't have "Update.esm", A file that I have verified I do

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, nexus-mod-manager

Needing a little help troubleshooting this problem.
I have the latest version of Nexus Mod Manager with the intent to mod Skyrim with all its massive collection of content from the community. I have used the Mod Manager in the past, but only recently had any issues. Lately, when I try to tell the Mod Manager to connect to Skyrim, I get the following error:

"You are missing D:\Games\steamapps\common\The Elder Scrolls V Skyrim\Data\Upate.esm. Please verify your game installation and ensure D:\Games\steamapps\common\The Elder Scrolls V Skyrim\Data\Upate.esm is present."

Here are the actions I have attempted so far to try and fix this:

- Verify my game installation through steam
- Updated my NMM, Skyrim installation, and drivers
- Navigate to the file myself and verify that "Update.esm" was present in that location
- Used programs like LOOT and Wyre Bash that also clarified I had a working Update.esm file
- Uninstalled what mods I had from NMM, Steam Workshop, and separate mods I installed on my own

Any advice would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Are you running NMM as an Administrator?

Comment: I assume "Upate.esm" is a typo?

Comment: This seems very odd to me.  The directory should be ...\steamapps\common\\**skyrim**\Data\Update.esm.  At least, that's what I have on my computer.